# Como copiar um datagrid para um arraylist

Tags: c#, array, datagridview

Eu tenho um botão e comando e quando clico nele, preciso copiar todas as informações do meu datagrid para um Arraylist. Por ex: O datagrid tem 4 colunas e 10 linhas todas tem informações, agora vem meu dilema, ao clicar no batão preciso copiar todo datragrid para um arrylista. estou usando o seguinte cód.

```
ArrayList Array = new ArrayList();    
foreach (DataGridViewCell item in dgvCompeticao.CurrentRow.Cells)
{
  Array.Add(item.Value);
}
```

Mas esse cód está copiando apenas a linha

Comment: Já tentou adicionar também as colunas no código?

Comment: Você quer copiar todas as linhas para a lista? Ou quer copiar todas as células de todas as linhas? Se for a segunda, como as células ficarão organizadas dentro da lista? Você terá lista de listas? Já aviso para usar o `List` no lugar do `ArrayList`. Não que afete o seu problema, afeta todos os problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meu código ficou assim

```
string[,] myList = new string[dataGridView1.ColumnCount, dataGridView1.RowCount]; //define o tamanho da variavel

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount-1; i++) //percorre as linhas 
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; x++) // percorre as colunas
        {
            if (dgvCompeticao[x, i].Value != null)
               {
                 myList[x, i] = dgvCompeticao[x, i].Value.ToString();
           }
        }
    }
```

Assim  funcionou legal. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Coloca esse código no seu button e testa;
( lembrando que eu coloquei **04 colunas** no DGV )

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) //carrega os itens
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Linha= " + i.ToString() + "\t Coluna=0 ",
                                   "Linha= " + i.ToString() + "\t Coluna=1 ",
                                   "Linha= " + i.ToString() + "\t Coluna=2 ",
                                   "Linha= " + i.ToString() + "\t Coluna=3 ");
        }

        string[,] myList = new string[dataGridView1.ColumnCount, dataGridView1.RowCount]; //define o tamanho da variavel

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount-1; i++) //percorre as linhas 
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; x++) // percorre as colunas
            {
                myList[x, i] = dataGridView1[x, i].Value.ToString();
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show(myList[2, 2]); //pega o resultado
```

Comment: Você está criando uma tabela no 1º for?

Comment: Sim, pra ter um ponto de onde começar no código.

Comment: Isso é só um exemplo, eu preenchi o DGV, depois criei a variavel, preenchi ela, depois mostrei o resultado da posição que queria pelo MsgBox, e SIM, foi testado sim.

Comment: @ClevertonCarneiro eu entendi isso, mas e qndo tiver celula vazia? o tostring(), não aceita e agora? Esse é meu casso tá dando essa msg de exceção:   
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @ClevertonCarneiro, tem como jogar esse conteúdo em um variável tipo datetable?

Answer (score 1):

Segue exemplo com DataTable

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Linha= " + i.ToString() + "\t Coluna=0 ",
                               "Linha= " + i.ToString() + "\t Coluna=1 ",
                               "Linha= " + i.ToString() + "\t Coluna=2 ",
                               "Linha= " + i.ToString() + "\t Coluna=3 ");
    }


    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

    //criação das colunas do datatable
    for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; x++)
    {
        // o tipo de dados vc pode definir (int) (datetime) (decimal) e por ai vai
        dt.Columns.Add(dataGridView1.Columns[x].HeaderText, typeof(string)); 
    }

    //criação das colunas do datatable passagem do dados para o dataTable
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(""); //aqui vc cria a coluna
        for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; x++)
        {
            //aqui vc atribuir o valor a coluna
            dt.Rows[i][x] = dataGridView1[x, i].Value.ToString();                    
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[2][2].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tem de fazer um loop externo que obtém as linhas, e um loop aninhado para pegar as células dessa linha.

Similar a isto aqui:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvCompeticao.Rows) {
  ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
  foreach (DataGridViewCell item in row.Cells) {
    array.Add(item.Value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Você testou isso? Creio que não irá funcionar

Comment: Eu disse **similar**. A ideia é percorrer uma linha por vez, e então adicionar os valores das células no array.

Comment: Essa não deu amigo @mutlei